# How can I pack some information from struct in 2 Bytes buffer?

Tags: c

I have struct in this form:

```
struct args {
  uint16_t portnum;   /**< port number */
  const char *portstr;/**< port number as string */
  cmd_t cmd;          /**< command (GET, SET) */
  uint8_t value;      /**< set value */
  uint8_t id;         /**< device id */
};

struct args arguments =
    { DEFAULT_PORTNUM, DEFAULT_PORTNUM_STR, UNDEF, 0, 0 };
```

I need to extract "id,cmd,value" from arguments and save them in 2 bytes buffer in this form:

[image]

arguments.value has max value of 127 so 7th bit is unused

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
uint8_t buf[2];
buf[0] = arguments.cmd | arguments.id << 2;
buf[1] = arguments.value >> 1;

if(send(sockfd, buf, 2, 0) < 0 ){
   //error
}
```

Comment: You should look into bitfields

Comment: Hard to guess what "doesn't work" is supposed to mean.  You shouldn't shift arguments.value, use it as-is.

Comment: Why are you shifting the value right?! doesn't that just mean that the value is from 0 to 127 with MSB bit unset or ignored

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry yes it is not clear, I'm trying for almost 2h :/ ... So what I meant is that my "solution" doesn't store info as shown in picture

Comment: So you want to write a function `void pack_args(cmd_t cmd, uint8_t id, uint8_t value, uint8_t dest[2])` that packs cmd, id and value into two byte buffer? What are permissible values for each arguments and what is `cmd_t` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk
Yes, exactly.
cmd_t is enum

typedef enum {
  GET = 0,
  SET = 1,
  UNDEF = 2
} cmd_t;


ID ∈ [0, 63] , VALUE ∈ [0, 127]

Comment: If `value` is betwen `0` and `127`, then don't shift it to the right` `value >> 1`. `>> 1` is the same as division by 2. Just store `buf[1] = value`. Now to the `id`. `id` has values between `0` and `63`?

Comment: I'd have to guess you are thrown-off by that 7th bit in the 2nd byte not being used.  What it *meant* to say is that it always should be 0.  So do not shift, at most you should check that arguments.value is not larger than 127.  Because if it would then that 7th bit would be used and be 1.

Comment: @KamilCuk oooh ok i see it now, thanks for explaining. Yes id has values between 0 and 63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cmd_t is enum typedef enum { GET = 0, SET = 1, UNDEF = 2 } cmd_t;
>   ID ∈ [0, 63] ,
>   VALUE ∈ [0, 127]

Just don't shift `value` to the right. `>> 1` is (logically) equal to division by 2 `/ 2`.

```
buf[0] = arguments.cmd | arguments.id << 2;
buf[1] = arguments.value;
```

The MSB bit of `buf[1]` is "unused" - will be set to zero, from `arguments.value`.

Remember it's good to implement assertions or other error-checking-mechanisms to make your functions extra safe:

```
assert(0 <= arguments.cmd && arguments.cmd <= 2);
assert(0 <= arguments.id && arguments.id <= 63);
assert(0 <= arguments.value && arguments.value <= 127);
```

And you may mask the values so nothing strange will ever happen, as suggested by @bolson in his answer

```
buf[0] = (arguments.cmd & 0x3) | ((arguments.id << 2) & 0xfc);
buf[1] = arguments.value & 0x7f;
```

Answer (score 0):

be more explicit with masking the bits you want to keep or drop

```
buf[0] = (arguments.cmd & 0x03) | ((arguments.id & 0x3f) << 2);
buf[1] = (arguments.value >> 1) & 0x7f;
```

Comment: why `(arguments.value >> 1)` ? you loose the lower bit, just do `buf[1] = arguments.value;` or `buf[1] = arguments.value & 0x7f` if you prefer